# PHP array_replace without creating keys

Tags: php

I am trying to overwrite the elements of one array with values from another – *without* creating additional elements in the process.

For example:

```
$base = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana');
$replace = array('a' => 'orange', 'b' => 'grape', 'c' => 'cauliflower');
```

Merge the arrays to create:

```
array('a' => 'orange', 'b' => 'grape'); // 'c' not included
```

Using **array_merge** or **array_replace** would properly overwrite the elements, but the resulting array would include elements not found in the first array.

How can I combine two arrays to create an array containing only keys from the first array, and the corresponding values from a second array?

Is there an existing PHP array function that can do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) and [`array_merge`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to do it:

```
$result = array_merge($base, array_intersect_key($replace, $base));
```

`array_intersect_key` isolates those elements of `$replace` with keys that already exist in `$base` (ensuring that new elements will not appear in the result) and `array_merge` replaces the values in `$base` with these new values from `$replace` (while ensuring that keys appearing only in `$base` will retain their original values).

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/b8Fu6X)**.

It is interesting to note that the same result can also be reached with the order of the calls reversed:

```
$result = array_intersect_key(array_merge($base, $replace), $base);
```

However this version does slightly more work, so I recommend the first one.

Comment: why not just array_intersect_key($replace, $base) ? while checking the documentation [link] http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php "Also notice that the values for the keys 'blue' and 'green' differ between the two arrays. A match still occurs because only the keys are checked. The values returned are those of array1." So i dont think array_merge is required..

Comment: @coderkane: Because if `$replace` does not contain all the keys that `$base` has the result will have missing values.

Comment: I am aware, but the OP did say he wants values only from the second array. However, it is possible that he didn't foresee that scenario, so good point out.

Comment: @coderkane: "Overwrite elements of one array with values from another" -- IMHO this says the elements not in the other array should retain their existing values.

Answer (score 2):

```
print_r(array_intersect_key($replace, $base));
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I knew there had to be a simple solution.

Comment: @Jason: Please be aware that if `$replace` does not have values for all the keys in `$base` then the "missing" keys will not appear in the result at all.

Comment: Note that in this version, the resulting array will have keys in the order they appear in $replace, not $base - in case it matters

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a built in method for that, however, it would be trivial with a loop and `array_key_exists`.

```
foreach( $replace as $k => $v )
{
   if ( array_key_exists( $k, $base ) )
      $base[ $k ] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following should do it:

```
foreach ($replace as $k => $v)
   if (isset($base[$k])) $base[$k]=$v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = array_replace($base, array_intersect_key($replace, $base));
```