# replace array key values in a file by PHP

Tags: php

I want to edit values in a array php file.

```
this is lang.php    
$lang = array (
    'l_name' => "Language",
    'b' => "Break");
```

I want to replace `'l_name' => "Language",` into `'l_name' => "Hi its me.",`

how I can do it?

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$search = array('l_name');
$replace = array('Hi, its me');
$newContents = str_replace($search, $replace, $fileContents);
$handle = fopen($path_to_file ,"w");
fwrite($handle, $newContents);
fclose($handle);
```

I tried this but its not working its replacing the key `'l_name'`

I want to replace to value of key, How can i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code and replace it accordingly.

```
<?php

//Replace 'l_name' key value:
echo "\n\nReplace 'l_name' key value: \n";
$lang = array (
    'l_name' => "Language",
    'b' => "Break");
$search = $lang['l_name'];
$replace = 'Hi, its me';
$newContents = str_replace($search, $replace, $lang);
print_r($newContents);

//Replace all key value
$newArr = array();
foreach($lang as $key=>$val)
{
  $newArr[$key] = 'Hi, its me';
}

echo "\n\nReplace all key value: \n";
print_r($newArr);
```

**Output**

```
Replace 'l_name' key value: 
Array
(
    [l_name] => Hi, its me
    [b] => Break
)


Replace all key value: 
Array
(
    [l_name] => Hi, its me
    [b] => Hi, its me
)
```

**Demo: [Click Here](https://eval.in/822307)**

Comment: Thanks bro its worked. But to replace all keys inside `$lang` ?

Comment: You have written that you need to replace only `l_name` value.

Comment: can't we use here `$lang['l_name'];` something? so that `$lang` can get all key ?

Comment: Give me your desire output. You need to replace for all keys with same replace value?

Comment: no, no, I need to replace all key with different values.
`Output

Array
(
    [l_name] => Hi, its me
    [b] => Break
     [c] => another

)
`

Comment: Your $lang array with 2 key and now your desire output giving as 3 key value to replace. If you need to replace all key with same value then that code I have updated please check it.

Comment: thanks bro, does it possible to replace all key with different values ?

Comment: Yes, Its possible. You can achieve it by forloop and `array_replace()` function.

Comment: Check example  here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240493/php-array-replace-without-creating-keys